# Split numpy array according to array containing bounds without for loop

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have an 1-D array with some values as

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,5,6,8,9,11,12,13,14,15])
```

I also have another array with some values as

```
b = np.array([0,3,6,9,12,15,18])
```

I need to split array `a` in such a way that the first array should have elements with values between `b[0]` and `b[1]`, the second array should have elements with values between `b[1]` and `b[2]`, and so on. So the results would be the following

```
result = [[1,2],
          [3,5],
          [6,8],
          [9,11],
          [12,13,14],
          [15]]
```

I know how to do this using a for loop but that's way too slow. Would there be a faster way?

Comment: no, given the output is a ragged array, for loop is pretty much all you can do.

Comment: Is it ok to let `result` be a list of `np.ndarrays` (e.g. `[array([1, 2]),
 array([3, 5]), ...]`), rather than a list of `lists`? If so, you could use `np.split`.

Comment: it's not a problem to have `result` as a list of `np.ndarrays`, but `np.split` does not solve the problem because it considers array `b` as a list of index, but I want to divide `a` according to the values of the elements of `b`, which will be float numbers in my real problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try as follows. First, we use [`np.searchsorted`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) with `side` parameter set to `left` to "[f]ind indices where elements [from `a`] should be inserted to maintain order [inside `b`]". So:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3,5,6,8,9,11,12,13,14,15])
b = np.array([0,3,6,9,12,15,18])

a_in_b = np.searchsorted(a, b, side='left')
# array([ 0,  2,  4,  6,  8, 11, 12], dtype=int64)
```

Next, we feed this array to [`np.split`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) as the `indices_or_sections` parameter, and receive a list of `np.ndarrays`. Finally, we cut off the first and last ones, as they will be empty (i.e. `array([], dtype=int32)`).

```
res = np.split(a, a_in_b, axis=0)[1:-1]
print(res)

[array([1, 2]),
 array([3, 5]),
 array([6, 8]),
 array([ 9, 11]),
 array([12, 13, 14]),
 array([15])]
```

Let me know if you run into any complications applying this method to your actual data.

Comment: @TiagoKalile: If the answer offers a solution to your problem, please consider accepting it to close the question.